# Books on Markov processes, with emphasis on continuous-time

Tags: reference-request, markov-process

Is there a comprehensive book on continuous-time Markov processes that doesn't completely focus on diffusions? I know the book of Liggett (*Continuous Time Markov Processes*), but find myself way too often looking things up that are not in that book. *Markov Processes, Brownian Motion, and Time Symmetry* by Kai Lai Chung is pretty inexpensive, but I have no experience with it. I realize this is a broad question, but I feel there is a gaping hole in my probability theory library.

Comment: Are you looking for a more theory focused or application focused?

Comment: More theory-focused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book [*Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319310886) by Le Gall, there is a chapter called "General Theory of Markov Processes." While the book is not about Markov processes, Le Gall mentions some references in the notes at the end of the book:

> The reader interested in the more general theory of Markov processes may have a look at the classical books of [Blumenthal and Getoor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486462633), [Meyer](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540039013), and [Sharpe](https://books.google.com/books/about/General_Theory_of_Markov_Processes.html?id=lMpIvtIgFiMC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I have not read any of these books but I plan to give Sharpe's book a look, after I have finished with Le Gall's book.